# We know log_add, but how to do log_subtract?

Tags: function, math, numbers

*Multiplying* two numbers in log space means adding them:

```
log_multiply(x, y) = log( exp(x) * exp(y) )
                   = x + y
```

*Adding* two numbers in log space means you do a special log-add operation:

```
log_add(x, y) = log( exp(x) + exp(y) )
```

which is implemented in the following code, in a way that doesn't require us to take the two exponentials (and lose runtime speed and precision):

```
  double log_add(double x, double y) {
    if(x == neginf)
      return y;
    if(y == neginf)
      return x;
    return max(x, y) + log1p(exp( -fabs(x - y) ));
  }
```

([Here](http://www.csee.usf.edu/~murphy/Temp/download/Toolboxes/Trulla%20Toolbox/Level%204/Example/trulla.smooth/include/evolution/core/math/MathUtils.hpp) is another one.)

But here is the question:

**Is there a trick to do it for subtraction as well?**

```
log_subtract(x, y) = log( exp(x) - exp(y) )
```

without having to take the exponents and lose precision?

```
  double log_subtract(double x, double y) {
    // ?
  }
```

Comment: By the way, log(exp(x)*exp(y)) == x+y, not log(x+y).

Comment: +1 just 'cause I consider myself well-versed in mathematics and I've never heard of that identity.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about

```
double log_subtract(double x, double y) {
  if(x <= y)
    // error!! computing the log of a negative number
  if(y == neginf)
    return x;
  return x + log1p(-exp(y-x));
}
```

That's just based on some quick math I did...

Comment: I had just come to the same thing.  Thought for sure I was going to get my first upvote, but you beat me.

Comment: Cool. Should be if(x<y) in the 2nd line, I guess.

Comment: I used <= because if x == y, you'd wind up taking the logarithm of 0, which is undefined.

Comment: logarithm of 0 is fine: log(0)=-inf, exp(-inf)=0

Comment: Well... if it's convenient to do it that way in your program, go right ahead, but mathematically that's not true. The *limit* of log(x) as x goes to 0 (for positive x) is indeed -inf, but log(0) itself has no value.

Comment: Well ... mathematically, the limit of log(x), x->+0 does not exist.

Comment: Yeah, I just often use some form of infinity to denote nonexistent limits. (I'm a physicist, for my purposes they're pretty much the same thing ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The library functions for exp and log lose precision for extreme values.
log1p gets you half way there, but what you need is a function that treats the error for both the log and the exp parts.

See this article: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/vignettes/log1mexp-note.pdf

The title is "Accurately Computing log(1 - exp(-|a|))".

The article discusses how to seemlessly merge different algorithms to create good error bounds for a larger range of inputs.